# Unexpected centroid calculations using sp::Polygon@labpt

Tags: r, maps, geospatial

I was recently calculating centroids for a mapping project and I noticed a number of suspicious locations. For example, the `labpt` output for japan is far outsize its latitude range. My first question is whats happening here? My second question is whether there is a good alternative for centroid calculation that will get the centroid correctly.

```
library(sp)
library(maps)

japan <- map_data("world",region="japan")

> max(japan$lat)
[1] 45.50952
> min(japan$lat)
[1] 24.26606

max(japan$long)
[1] 145.833
min(japan$long)
[1] 123.6789

# note 63 is calculated Latitude for Japan
sp::Polygon(japan[c("long","lat")])@labpt
[1] 130.32951  63.62904
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of googling and I've come up with the following:

```
library(rgeos)

rgeos::gCentroid(SpatialPoints(japan[c('long','lat')]))

SpatialPoints:
     x        y
1 135.2924 35.47393
```